# Android sorting optimization

Tags: java, android, sorting, optimization

I am working on an Android app.  I want to implement a function that when clicking a button the data （files with their sizes）shown on the screen is sorted. Here I sort the files by file sizes using `Comparator<>` in android:  Comparator `ascSort` and Comparator `descSort`, then return them into `Collections.sort()` and decide the sorting order by the boolean value of `isClick`. `FileMangeBean` is a bean of file data that allows calling `getFileSize()`.

Here is the problem: Is there any approach to optimize the sorting, like merging `ascSort` and `descSort` into one `Sort`?
Also, welcome to provide more ideas on sorting data(files) by their sizes in android if you have.

```
switch(...){
    case R.id.file_size_sort_button:
        isClick = !isClick;     // boolean value: isClick 
        
        // display files ascendingly or descendingly in size
        Collections.sort(fileSizeData, isClick ? ascSort : descSort);    
        
        // set an icon according to isClick 
        aImageView.setImageResource(isClick ? R.drawable.close_icon : R.drawable.open_icon);
```

```
private Comparator<FileManageBean> descSort = (o1, o2) -> {
    long size1 = o1.getFileSize();
    long size2 = o2.getFileSize();
    return Long.compare(size2, size1);
};

private Comparator<FileManageBean> ascSort = (o1, o2) -> {
    long size1 = o1.getFileSize();
    long size2 = o2.getFileSize();
    return Long.compare(size1, size2);
};
```

Comment: `Collections.sort` is already optimized u can't do much about it . If u want to sorting only once then can just have two extra sorted List or just one that will allow u to just use the already sorted list if u have all the data in list at once(Without pagination) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mean the performance optimization, you can use `Comparator::reversed()`.

```java
Collections.sort(fileSizeData, isClick ? ascSort : ascSort.reversed());
```

Then just delete the `descSort`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need ascsort and descsort?  One is the reverse of the other-  just use one and reverse it when you want the other way.  Merging the two wouldn't make things more efficient, it would slow down the comparator compared to a simple one and cause the sort to take more time-  you want a comparator to have the minimum code possible.

If you really want to speed things up-  don't call getFileSize in the comparison.  That requires a call to disk to get the information.  Get all the file sizes once, cache that info, then sort based on the cached data.  That will speed things up significantly if you sort multiple times.